# How to create deb package that can be used on different versions of Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, build, deb

I've created package clarity-icon-theme ppa:jcubic/jcubicppa but only for Maverik I have lines like this in debian/changelog file

```
clarity-icon-theme (0.3) maverick; urgency=low
  * Add missing symlinks
 -- Jakub Jankiewicz (jcubic) <jcubic [at] onet [dot] pl>  Fri, 14 Oct 2011 19:05:01 +0200
```

How can I create a package that can be used by Lucid, Natty and newers versions of Ubuntu? Do I need to create separated packages?

Comment: Try Askubuntu.com. (Ubuntu.SE.)

Comment: @muntoo: absolutely not gonna work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create separate packages.  This is because of the potential of different library versions being required in various versions of Ubuntu.

As well, when you build the packages into the binaries, it will be building *only* for the libraries available within that version of Ubuntu.

Subsequently, this is why in `debian/changelog` you are only allowed to specify one version of Ubuntu at a time.

Take a look at the files in my `rkhunter` backports PPA: https://launchpad.net/~trekcaptainusa-tw/+archive/rkhunter  Feel free to see what the changelog entries show, and how I named the package version numbers (you can omit the ~ppa# part at the end, but you should append the version of ubuntu to the package names if you're building for more than one version of Ubuntu, and then build each separately).

Comment: Not true; while it might make sense for a package with very strict dependency requirements, in the general case a package built for one version will install and very often just plain work on a newer version.  For an icon theme, the whole point of different library versions is very far-fetched.  If you want to look for examples, there are many packages which have not been updated since Maverick, so Natty and Oneiric use the same exact .deb file.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. You need to work out what the limitations for this particular package are. If it depends on a library that's at an incompatible ABI version in a different release, then the package can't be supported on both releases.

An icon theme probably only contains data, so it should be easy enough to get working on all releases.